# max-width and max-height for fluid images not working in IE10

Tags: image, responsive-design, internet-explorer-10, css

I'm trying to make a semi-responsive design on my website. And for that I use percentage for the width and height of everything except the page-wrapper, where I set a `max-width` in pixels.

I also put `max-width` and `max-height` equal 100% on my pictures, so that when people decrease their browser size, so will the images and follow along with the rest of the content. This is working as intended in Chrome, but in IE10 it does not. As far as I can see, it's only when I put my pictures in divs that have `display: table-cell`

Without the picture in the div, the div increases or decreases according to the window size, just as it should, in both IE and Chrome. But when I put in an image with `style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;"`, then it doesn't scale, not in IE at least.

Is this a bug, or is it working as intended. And is there anything I can do ? :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem occurs in IE, Firefox, and Opera. With some types of content, it also occurs in Chrome and Safari. In short, this appears to be a limitation of table cells. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16397667/1306809

Answer (score 2):

This IS a bug in IE...but you can often fix it by making the table container have a table-layout attribute equal to 'fixed'.

Answer (score 0):

Add !DOCTYPE to the top of the page to get max-width and max-height working in IE, e.g.:
< !DOCTYPE html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Strict//en" >

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530811(v=vs.85).aspx